# Bundler, ExecJS, Mac OS X and Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, bundler

I'm developing Rails on Mac OS X 10.8 and trying to use *Capistrano* to deploy to **Debian Squeeze**.

Deploying gives me this error:

```
Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources
```

It seems to be that I have `bundle package`-d a Mac OS X binary gem:

```
Updating files in vendor/cache
...
* libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-12.gem
```

The `Gemfile` has:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

I want to use binary gems because Squeeze does not provide Node.js from package manager and I would like to keep source compiling out of production server.

Is there any way to tell Bundler to package **both** Linux and Darwin binaries?

BTW, how does `therubyracer` accomplish this when it too [uses Bundler](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/blob/master/Gemfile)?

Comment: Cross-compiling from MacOS for Linux? You're in for some pain.

Comment: I don't mean crosscompiling. The `libv8` gem has binary variants for both Linux and Mac. I want to package them both.

Comment: Native extensions are compiled when you install them.

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of binary gems is to cut the compile time and ship with precompiled binaries for given platform. E.g `wkhtmltopdf-binary` comes with [precompiled binaries for **three** platforms](https://github.com/steerio/wkhtmltopdf-binary/tree/master/libexec). My problem is that `libv8` has **platform-specific versioning** and one gem contains only single binary for that one platform. I would've liked to include binaries for two platforms in the Bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution was to skip `bundle package` which would download all packages from source, but his made deploy **too slow** for my taste (probably b/c for some reason it still didn't download binary gem and compiled libv8 afresh each time).

So I ended up installing `Node.js` from source to the Debian box and document that as a prerequirement for the project. Then I commented out this part of `Gemfile`:

```
group :assets do
  ...
  # gem 'therubyracer'
  ...
end
```

Now I can again `bundle package` the whole lot and deploy fast.

Answer (score 0):

Install `libv8` on your Debian box.

Comment: I tried, but Capistrano uses `bundle --deployment` which doesn't use system installed gems.